# What app icon is this?

Tags: macos, menu-bar

This app icon appeared on my MacOS system menu bar above. Clicking on it doesn't appear to do anything. Anyone recognize it?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the LibreOffice update utility! It's update window was hiding in the back.